# Is there an alternative to loading a class with Class.forName()?

Tags: java, osgi, classloader

In my library's code, I load class names from an XML file using JAXB, in order to instanciate them later on using [`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29). A fictive example to illustrate the case:

```
public void libraryMethod() throws Exception {
  List<String> classNames = loadClassNamesFromXML();

  for (String className : classNames) {
    Class.forName(className).newInstance().doThings();
  }
}
```

Now, some users use OSGi to configure their applications, and they load my library with a different class loader than the classes they configure using my XML structure. This means that loading may fail, as the class cannot be found.

Is there any more reliable way to load such classes? Or is there any other way to configure these instances? I'm open to suggestions that result in this:

```
public void libraryMethod() throws Exception {
  // Spring does things like this:
  List<SomeType> instances = loadInstancesFromXML();

  for (SomeType instance : instances) {
    instance.doThings();
  }
}
```

Some constraints:

- From a library perspective, the lifecycle of those instances is unimportant. If they have (user) state, my library would not notice.
- I want to keep things simple in this library, so I want to avoid creating external dependencies on configuration frameworks like spring, for instance. So I'm only interested in solutions that can be achieved with standard JDK 6+ distributions.
- I would really like to keep my simple XML configuration file (slight adaptations to the XML structure are OK).

Comment: You are already quite deep in a special solution without showing the real problem you try to solve. Can you explain what your xml config does and why you have to load classes from other bundles without importing their packages?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: I write a library ([jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)). I cannot import arbitrary user packages, but I'd like library users to be able to inject implementations of `SomeType` into my library. With spring, it would be quite easy to inject such implementations, but that would mean that my library would have a "heavy" dependency on spring itself.

Comment: @PreethiJain: I doubt that you have closely read my question, it is more specific than you probably thought...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your library to be flexible and work in both OSGi and non-OSGi environment, you should allow users provide their own ClassLoader's or let them tell your library which class names they have. Read [Neil Bartlett blog post](http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/30/osgi-readiness-loading-classes.html).

Original link returns a 404. You can access the article on the [Wayback Machine.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150217082541/http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/30/osgi-readiness-loading-classes.html)

Comment: Neil being the ultimate authority, there's no reason to discuss this further :-) As he concludes, stop guessing.

Comment: Link to the blog post 404's.

Comment: It's available on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150217082541/http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/30/osgi-readiness-loading-classes.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the explanation. Spring would not make this any easier in OSGi. You can not simply inject an implementation class from a package you do not import. In OSGi you typically use OSGi services to inject implementations that originate outside your bundle and are unknown to you at compile time.

So your user would implement an interface you specify and publish his implementation as an OSGi service. You could then either pick up all such services or let the user specify an ldap filter for his service in the xml config.

The advantage of this aproach is that you do not have to load classes and care about classloaders. So this is the recommended way in OSGi. If you want the same solution for inside and outside OSGi Ivan's aproach with specifying a classloader + classname is an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. The reason why I thought that spring could be a solution is because those particular users who have problems with jOOQ/OSGi build [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) themselves and probably patched it. But good to know that this doesn't generally work. LDAP sounds like overkill, but services may be a good idea. Allowing to specify a custom class loader seems to be the best option so far, although @MarkoTopolnik's context class loader seemed to work as a workaround.

Comment: When you filter for services impls in OSGi you can use a filter in LDAP syntax. This is not something special it is available in all OSGi frameworks. The one who publishes the service can give it properties and the one who searches for a service uses these filters on the properties to search. If you use the service aproach you do not need a classloader but you depend on OSGi then.

Answer (score 2):

In general, in OSGi you should use a service. The reason that Class.forName/XML configuration is so popular is that only a single class gets control. To configure the rest, it needs to know the classes to initialize/call.

In OSGi this problem does not exist since each module (bundle) (can) get control through declarative services (or in the old fashioned way through an activator). So in OSGi you have a peer to peer model. Anybody can register a service and depend on other services.

So instead of specifying class names and assuming they are globally unique (they are not in  large systems) it is a lot easier to use services and not leave the Java compiler; these class names are very error prone. In general this means that you often just register your service and wait to be called since there is no need to initialize your clients. However, the whiteboard pattern address the situation when you want to find out about your clients (with bndtools and bnd annotations):

The "server"

```
@Component
public class MyLib {
   @Reference(type='*')
   void addSomeType(SomeType st ) {
      st.doThings();
   }
}
```

The client

```
@Component
public class MyClient implements SomeType {
  public void doThings() { ... }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is interesting. However, I wouldn't like to introduce so much of OSGi in my library, as library users who do not use OSGi should also be able to profit from this functionality...

Comment: Actually, looking at jooq, you probably want to make life more modular and support the _extender_ pattern. In OSGi, it is trivial to track bundles that become active

Answer (score 1):

JDBC4 drivers include META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver in the jar which use the ServiceProvider mechanism to register the Driver implementation with the JVM (see [java.util.ServiceLoader](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) javadocs). Having the driver on the class path will register the driver automatically, obviating the need to use Class.forName. Instead app code uses ServiceLoader.load to discover registered drivers. Same mechanism can be used for other config. Perhaps something like that could be used? As an aside, when registering one's own implementations with the Service Provider mechanism, using an annotation like the [spi](http://code.google.com/p/spi/) looks pretty convenient.

Comment: Yeah. ServiceProvider is another broken parody on the Service Registry. However, if 100% OSGi is not an option, ServiceProvider is still better than nothing. It will not help with classloaders, though.

Comment: @IvanDubrov: Interesting. Could you explain what the "class loading problem" would be, if I used a ServiceProvider?

Comment: It either uses ThreadContext classloader (which is broken in OSGi), or requires you to provide single classloader explicitly, but in OSGi there could be multiple bundles providing services and as a result you have several classloaders.